# Java : I want to change an integer array into a mathematical number

Tags: java

Here is my array, it consists of array of integers. Actually, these are the key of my  HashMap which consists of some sentences or say "STRING" of a complete paragraph as a key value pair. Now I wanted to join those sentences from taking the key from the integer array one after another in given order.

```
 int[] arr = {3, 2, 0, 5, 3};

 HashMap<Integer, String> h = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{
      put(0,"This is my third sentence.");
      put(3,"This is my first sentence.");
      put(5,"This is my forth sentence.");
      put(2,"This is my second sentence.");
 }};
```

The final output should be all the sentences combined as mentioned order and outout should be like a paragraph as :

This is my first sentence.This is my second sentence.This is my third sentence.
This is my forth sentence.This is my first sentence.

Comment: This needs only 1 loop, that's it. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of converting the value to a character type you can perform *math*. For each digit in the array, the corresponding power of 10 is the array length (minus one) minus the index (because Java arrays use `0` based indexing and the last digit corresponds to 10<sup>0</sup>). Something like,

```
int[] arr = { 3, 2, 0, 5, 3 };
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result += arr[i] * Math.pow(10, arr.length - i - 1);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Output is (as expected)

```
32053
```

Optimization

It's possible to *optimize* the code further by keeping the current power of ten and dividing `10` while iterating each digit. This would also allow the use of a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
int[] arr = { 3, 2, 0, 5, 3 };
int result = 0;
int pow = (int) Math.pow(10, arr.length - 1);
for (int digit : arr) {
    result += digit * pow;
    pow /= 10;
}
System.out.println(result);
```

**Alternatively**, iterate the digits from right to left and multiply `pow` by `10` on each iteration. That might look something like,

```
int result = 0;
int pow = 1;
for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    result += arr[i] * pow;
    pow *= 10;
}
```

And the above might also be written like

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = arr.length - 1, pow = 1; i >= 0; i--, pow *= 10) {
    result += arr[i] * pow;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I would guess that the pow call is expensive. I would have just multiple it by 10 in each loop.

Comment: @rekire True enough, I added a more *optimized* version.

Comment: Better yet, iterate using a for loop (instead of a for each) from last index to first and multiply by ten each time - that way you don't have to find the final power of ten you need for the first index, thus eliminating the `Math.pow` call entirely.

Answer (score 2):

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Comment: Man I was thinking about to write it those way for trolling.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
int[] arr = {3, 2, 0, 5, 3};
int i = Integer.parseInt(Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll("[\\[,\\] ]", ""));
System.out.println(i); // prints 32053
```

Answer (score 1):

Though fairly simple, you should have tried yourself.
Still providing a solution, just debug and understand it.

**Working Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] arr = {3, 2, 0, 5, 3};

        StringBuilder numberStr = new StringBuilder();
        for (int item : arr) {
            numberStr.append(item);
        }
        int finalInt = Integer.parseInt(numberStr.toString());
        System.out.println(finalInt);
    }
```

**Output**

```
32053
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert the array into string by appending elements one by one and the convert string into integer. Try this code:

```
 public class NewClass63 {
public static void main(String args[]){
int[] arr = {3, 2, 0, 5, 3};
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
   for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
       s.append(arr[i]);
   }
int x = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
    System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use a loop:

```
      int[] arr = { 3, 2, 0, 5, 3 };
        String itotal = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
           itotal=itotal + String.valueOf(arr[i]);
        }
        int a = Integer.parseInt(itotal);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array = {3,2,0,5,3};
String x = "";
for(int i = 0;i<=array.length-1;i++){
    x = x + String.valueOf(array[i]);
}
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(x));
```

Comment: this should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There exist various ways.
If I am right, hidden assumption is that the higher element of integer array matches with higher digit of result integer.

```
int[] arr = {3, 2, 0, 5, 3};
int result = 0;
int power = (int) Math.pow(10, arr.length-1);
for(int element : arr){
    result += element * power;
    power /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution answer is this.
Assume, each alphabet in the example is a single digit.

1. Empty Array {} : Expected value = 0
2. {a}: Expected value = a
3. {a,b}: Expected value = 10*a + b
4. {a,b,c}: Expected value = 10 * (10*a + b) + c

Code: Test this is [online java compiler IDE](https://kasadara.com/p/87ddf9f9-7375-452d-be20-24afea94f510)

```
public class ConvertDigitArrayToNumber {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {3, 2, 0, 5, 3};
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
      value = (10*value) + arr[i]; 
    }
    System.out.println(value);
  }
}
```

This is actually simpler and better solution than the other ones.

- Only simple multiplication and addition (No powers).
- No String conversions